# How to ignore empty values in hashmap?

Tags: java

I have the following string to put it to a map.

> [Name: 4/1, 
>            IP address: 000.000.00.01, IsOpticalInstalled: false, IsMPEGOutputActive: true, IsAutoNegotiationOn: true, LinkSpeed: AUTO,
>   , Mirror Of: , DSCP: 0,  sourceIPOrigin: current-ip-address]

```
outputPairs41=outputs41.next().trim();
        String[] outputPairsArray41=outputPairs41.split(",");      

        Map meOutputs41 = Stream.of(outputPairsArray41).map(
                s -> s.split(":",2))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s[0],  
                        Collectors.mapping(s -> s[1], Collectors.toList())));
```

There is a whitespace after LinkSpeed: AUTO which is breaking my code with error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1. Is there a way to ignore or add whitespaces as null to map?

I tried using `split(",",1)/(",",2)`. It did not work.

Comment: Note that there is no reason (in this code) to wrap `Arrays.asList` in `new ArrayList<String>(...)`. Or even to use `Arrays.asList`: just use `Stream.of(outputPairsArray41)`.

Comment: Also, don't use raw types: `Map<String, List<String>> meOutputs41`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a filter after the map, before the collect:

```
.map(s -> s.split(":",2))
.filter(arr -> arr.length == 2)  // Add this.
.collect(groupingBy(...))
```